# General considerations for NUI/touch interface

Tags: kinect, multi-touch, nui

For the past few months I've been looking into developing a Kinect based multitouch interface for a variety of software music synthesizers.

The overall strategy I've come up with is to create objects, either programatically or (if possible) algorithmically to represent various controls of the soft synth. These should have;

- X position
- Y position
- Height
- Width
- MIDI output channel
- MIDI data scaler (convert x-y coords to midi values)

2 strategies I've considered for agorithmic creation are XML description and somehow pulling stuff right off the screen (ie given a running program, find xycoords of all controls). I have no idea how to go about that second one, which is why I express it in such specific technical language ;). I could do some intermediate solution, like using mouse clicks on the corners of controls to generate an xml file. Another thing I could do, that I've seen frequently in flash apps, is to put the screen size into a variable and use math to build all interface objects in terms of screen size. Note that it isn't strictly necessary to make  the objects the same size as onscreen controls, or to represent all onscreen objects (some are just indicators, not interactive controls)

Other considerations;

Given (for now) two sets of X/Y coords as input (left and right hands), what is my best option for using them? My first instinct is/was to create some kind of focus test, where if the x/y coords fall within the interface object's bounds that object becomes active, and then becomes inactive if they fall outside some other smaller bounds for some period of time. The cheap solution I found was to use the left hand as the pointer/selector and the right as a controller, but it seems like I can do more. I have a few gesture solutions (hidden markov chains) I could screw around with. Not that they'd be easy to get to work, exactly, but it's something I could see myself doing given sufficient incentive.

So, to summarize, the problem is

- represent the interface (necessary because the default interface always expects mouse input)
- select a control
- manipulate it using two sets of x/y coords (rotary/continuous controller) or, in the case of switches, preferrably use a gesture to switch it without giving/taking focus.

Any comments, especially from people who have worked/are working in multitouch io/NUI, are greatly appreciated. Links to existing projects and/or some good reading material (books, sites, etc) would be a big help.

Comment: Meta-discussion about this question is happening/has happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106720/146495

Answer (score 2):

Woah lots of stuff here.  I worked on lots of NUI stuff during my at Microsoft so let's see what we can do...

But first, I need to get this pet peeve out of the way:  You say "Kinect based multitouch".  That's just wrong.  Kinect inherently has nothing to do with touch (which is why you have the "select a control" challenge).  The types of UI consideration needed for touch, body tracking, and mouse are totally different.  For example, in touch UI you have to be very careful about resizing things based on screen size/resolution/DPI... regardless of the screen, fingers are always the same physical size and people have the same degreee of physical accuracy so you want your buttons and similar controls to always be roughly the same physical size.  Research has found 3/4 of an inch to be the sweet spot for touchscreen buttons.  This isn't so much of a concern with Kinect though since you aren't directly touching anything - accuracy is dictated not by finger size but by sensor accuracy and users ability to precisely control finicky & lagging virtual cursors.

If you spend time playing with Kinect games, it quickly becomes clear that there are 4 interaction paradigms.
1) Pose-based commands.  User strikes and holds a pose to invoke some application-wide or command (usually brining up a menu)
2) Hover buttons.  User moves a virtual cursor over a button and holds still for a certain period of time to select the button
3) Swipe-based navigation and selection.  User waves their hands in one direction to scroll and list and another direction to select from the list
4) Voice commands.  User just speaks a command.

There are other mouse-like ideas that have been tried by hobbyists (havent seen these in an actual game) but frankly they suck:  1) using one hand for cursor and another hand to "click" where the cursor is or 2) using z-coordinate of the hand to determine whether to "click"

It's not clear to me whether you are asking about how to make some existing mouse widgets work with Kinect.  If so, there are some projects on the web that will show you how to control the mouse with Kinect input but that's lame.  It may sound super cool but you're really not at all taking advantage of what the device does best.

If I was building a music synthesizer, I would focus on approach #3 - swiping.  Something like Dance Central.  On the left side of the screen show a list of your MIDI controllers with some small visual indication of their status.  Let the user swipe their left hand to scroll through and select a controller from this list.  On the right side of the screen show how you are tracking the users right hand within some plane in front of their body.  Now you're letting them use both hands at the same time, giving immediate visual feedback of how each hand is being interpretted, and not requiring them to be super precise.

ps... I'd also like to give a shout out to Josh Blake's upcomming NUI book.  It's good stuff.  If you really want to master this area, go order a copy :) http://www.manning.com/blake/

Comment: Robert - thanks a bunch for your answer, good to see an ex-microsoft guy onboard. First, re kinect vs multitouch. I started out screwing around with various blob-tracking solutions awhile back, and gave up because when lighting conditions changed by the smallest margin imaginable, system response slowed to a crawl. I got into kinect because it handles blob tracking internally and outputs one or more x/y cursor coords. I have found that the resolution problem you mention (if we're talking about the same thing) still obtains for kinect because display resolutions and interface sizes differ.

Comment: Re mouse, the middleware I am using (primesense nite) essentially outputs 2 cursors in hand mode as well as a gesture-based click ("pushing" your hand toward the screen). I can use all of the joints(it outputs 10 or so, knees, hips, etc) if I so choose, tho I haven't felt like it yet. Re your swipe, that is the best I could actually come up with on my own. I am hoping other people have better ideas.

Comment: Here's an example of what I consider "better" - http://anythinghonest.com/amos/. It uses all the available features of the new tech (ipad in this case) in an intuitive way while providing deep control. I may steal parts of it for my thing. Thanks again for your help. Joe

Comment: I'm also aware of that book - looks pretty awsome, will have to pick it up.